# Table that is always at the top of the page

Tags: tables

I have created a command to generate a table with 7 arguments since I need to repeat it many times with different content. The problem I have is that when I create **the table using this command, it is always placed at the top of the page**. I have loaded the floats package, I have added H in the table header, I have also tried with !H but it returns an error ... I cannot find the cause of this Latex behavior regarding the position of a table with respect to the page. I add the definition **code of the command:**

```
\newcommand{\PTgen}[7]{
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \extrarowheight = -0.5ex
    \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{6pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
    \renewcommand {\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \renewcommand{\arrayrulewidth}{3pt}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ c |  c | c }
        $ #1 $ &$  #2 $ & \\ \hline
        $ #3 $ & $ #4 $ & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9} $ #5 $ \\ \hline
        & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9} $ #6 $ & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9} $ #7 $ \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table} 
}
```

**Invoking the command:**

```
\PTgen{1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7}
```

I would appreciate any suggestions that help me solve the problem.

Comment: What happens when you use `htbp` as float specifier (which should be the default)?

Comment: I've tried it, Werner, but the problem persists ...

Comment: unrelated to the float position but you are missing `%` at ends of lines here and `\extrarowheight = -0.5ex %Ajusta espacio superior entre filas para centrados` will, in general, cause rows in the table to over-print the row above with no warning.

Comment: The _only_ purpose of the `table` environment is to specify the tabular can be moved, if you do not want it to move, why are you using `table`?

Comment: @JesúsÁlvarezLobo: Then we'd need more detail, like a complete, minimal example, that replicates your current issue.

Comment: Please don't edit your question in a way that fundamentally alters the question after answers have been posted, it makes it impossible for people to understand the posted answer.

Comment: Thank you, David Carlisle, but if I delete the table all the text is centered! (?)

Comment: David, all I did was remove the comments preceded by % to prove that they don't need to end in % as you suggested. Thank you for your intention to help.

Comment: Solved! ... with the sugestion of  David Carlisle: I removed the table and substituted \centering by \begin{center}... \end{center}

Answer (score 5):

`[H]` is a special variant that should only be used sparingly and must be used alone, you can not use `[!H]`

Unrelated here but even with normal float arguments such as `htbp` You should not routinely add `!` as `!` means *ignore the document-specified constraints for this float*.  It does not make sense to ignore the constraints on *every* float: better to not use `!` and set more suitable constraints.

```
 \renewcommand {\tabcolsep}{3pt} %Ajusta espacio interior entre columnas
 \renewcommand{\arrayrulewidth}{3pt} %Ajusta el grueso de línea
```

Both of these are *lengths* and must be set with `\setlength` If you redefine them to be macros as here you will break latex's table code.

for example the standard (non-array package) `tabular` has

```
    \@addtopreamble{\hskip .5\arrayrulewidth}%
```

when `\arrayrulewidth` is a length this adds half its width. With your definition it expands to

```
    \@addtopreamble{\hskip .53pt}%
```

which accidentally is a valid length but not the intended length of half of 3pt/